# unable to add layer in keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am trying to following this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47537130/8100895).

```
outputs = Conv2DTranspose(3, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = bce, metrics = [mean_iou])
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_flatten(x)))
```

But at that last line of code, I receive the following error:

> 'Model' object has no attribute 'add'

I understand that since I didn't instantiate model as `sequential()` as in linked post, the function `add()` might not be available to me. However, I'm not sure how to work around this.

Comment: Is there something wrong if you add the Lambda layer after the Conv2DTranspose layer, i.e. `outputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_flatten(x))(outputs)`?

Comment: ^ that did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off @Today's answer in the OP's comments,

`outputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_flatten(x))(outputs)`

Answer (score 1):

Corrected to reflect the working solution:

```
outputs = Conv2DTranspose(3, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
outputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.batch_flatten(x))(outputs)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = bce, metrics = [mean_iou])
```

Comment: IN that situation, I got this error: `Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow Layer (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: <keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7f1beb736898>`